# Javascript: How to use "traditional OOP"

Tags: javascript, oop

I am working on a validator library, coming from PHP I would like to give the validation a similar set up with Validators and Constraints (The value, object gets validated by the validators against the selected constraints).

So working on the Constraints I have following issue:

The constraints all share the same properties just the implementation is slightly different.

Example:

```
Constraint = Validator.Constraint = {
    name: null, // contains the name of the constraint
    value: null, // contains the value which we want to validate
    options: {}, // contains options for some Constraints (e.g. range)
    message: null, // contains the error message which is getting returned
    validate: function(){}, // the validation logic
    constructor: function(value, options){ 
        this.value = value;
        this.options = options;
        this.validate(); 
    } // the constructor which can be called for stand-alone validation
};
```

Now I would like to somehow extend the Constraint and customize it:

```
RequiredConstraint = Validator.RequiredConstraint = {
    name: "required",
    message: "this property is required",
    validate: function(){
        if (this.value != "" || this.value != undefined || this.value != null) {
            return;
        }
        return this.message;
    }
    // other properties get inherited
};
```

The constrain then should be usable with:

```
RequiredConstraint("");
// returns false
```

I know would like to know two things:

1. At first if it is at all recommand to use this programming style even JavaScript is another language and too dynamic for this?
2. If it is still good practis how could I implement such behaviour as descriped above?
   What keywords do I have to look for?

Regards

Comment: I would suggest learning the *JavaScript way*, that is [prototypal inheritance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain). Then learn about [these advanced patterns](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/) when you get more comfy. For this particular case I would say don't reinvent the wheel and use [my own plugin](http://elclanrs.github.com/jq-idealforms/) to validate your form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put your functions in the prototype if you want them to be inherited.

Also, in ES3, the cleanest objects to inherit from are Functions.

Example:

```
function Constraint() {}

Constraint.prototype = {
    constructor: Constraint,

    validate: function() {
        console.log( 'Hello!' );
    },

    message: 'Property required!'
};

var RequiredConstraint = new Constraint();

RequiredConstraint.message; // "Property required!"
RequiredConstraint.validate(); // "Hello!"

// Now let's override it
RequiredConstraint.validate = function() {
    console.log( 'Hey!' );
};
RequiredConstraint.validate(); // "Hey!"
```

Answer (score 1):

Javascript can be confusing if you come from a Java, .NET, C++ background. In JS there is no concept of classes, everything is just another object. Even the function (that are used to simulate classes) are themselves objects. Have a look at below article to understand how things work under the hood.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_Revisited

As Florian said you need to use prototype based coding to simulate inheritance. But personally for me this style felt fishy every time I used it.

On the other hand, inheritance as a OOP concept is sometimes questionable and may prove as anti-patterns in most of the common usecases. My advice is for you to look for ways of achieving the same with composition, which may be a better style of programming for most of the scenarios.

Comment: Hey, your are right with what you say. Javascript seems very "boiler code"-like coming from the traditional OOP Background and I think it is really not a good idea to force JavaScript into known paradigmas. I will look a bit trough JavaScript design patterns (composition) to look how I can hold code more readable. I marked florians question as answer to stick to the strict stackoverflow conventions :)

Comment: @dev.pus A good link is this one if you want to see the patterns used in JS: http://javascript.info/tutorial/oop-concepts